# Update a gridview row within a Updatepanel by the click of a checkbox not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

**GOAL:**

I would like to update the status of the checkbox in the database when OnCheckedChanged event of the Checkbox fires. This checkbox resides on each row of gridview. Don't want to postback the whole page so I have the gridview inside a Updatepanel.

**PROBLEM:**

I can't get the OnCheckedChanged event to fire once the gridview is placed in a updatepanel.

or am I approaching this the wrong way?

---

Here is what i have for the updatepanel,gridview,checkbox and checkbox event code

The Binding of this gridview is within a `if (!IsPostBack)`

Even though it is not shown in this example below, that Gridview is nested in another gridview, if that makes a difference.

HTML

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="gridUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">  
<ContentTemplate>
     <asp:GridView ID="gvComponents" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid" OnRowDataBound="gvComponents_RowDataBound" ShowHeader="false">
        <Columns> 
            //Other TemplateFields
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Revisions Required" Visible="false"  ItemStyle-Width="10%" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbREVISION_REQD"  runat="server" Enabled="true" Checked='<%# (bool)Eval("REVISION") %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged ="cbREVISION_CheckChanged" />                                               
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
```

C#

```
protected void cbREVISION_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code to update the database
   gridUpdatePanel.Update();
}
```

Comment: So..... apparently this is working. I was just debugging wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be nothing wrong with the approach! But, is

```
UpdateMode="Conditional"
```

a problem?

Comment: The thought behind the UpdateMode as conditional was to not update on every postback regardless where it comes from on the page. 
Do you see a problem with this logic?

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this for binding nested-gridview in `cbREVISION_CheckChanged` event:

```
protected void cbREVISION_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = ((CheckBox)sender).Parent as GridViewRow; // gets the gridview row where checkbox cliked

        GridView gv = gvr.Parent as GridView; // gets the cliked gridview or nested gridview

        CheckBox chkbox = gvr.FindControl("cbREVISION_REQD") as CheckBox; // gets checkbox from cliked gridview

        bool status = chkbox.Checked; // gets the status of the checkbox

        // here bind your nested-gridview
        gv.DataSource = dt; // dt is some data to which you set gridview
        gv.DataBind(); // binding methed to bind gridview

    }
```

It will work!